# Is it possible to use Jackson views in combination with @JsonTypeName?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm working on an application where the serialized JSON includes the class name as a wrapper value. We need to continue supporting some of these names for legacy clients.

Using views, where the legacy object is the view and the new object is the instance, it's possible to get the correct fields serializing. However annotating the view with `@JsonTypeName` as well as `@JsonTypeInfo` is not causing the desired output.

So then, is it even possible to use a view to change the type name that the actual object instance would normally output?

Comment: Just for clarification: could you show your POJO classes and output which you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this had to do with a couple of things, namely my confusion of two different abstractions in Jackson: mixins and views. Plus a glitch related to static versus dynamic typing.